# WKWebView video inline iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I tried to play video embedded from youtube INLINE using WKWebView. However, I couldn't be able to fix that problem because my video still automatically go to full screen when I click to play it. I've spent several hours already, but I still couldn't find a solution yet. I'll appreciate your help, pls. Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var myPlayer: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let videoId = "9n1e1N0Sa9k"
    if let mediaURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(videoId)?playsinline=1") {
        let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: mediaURL)
        myPlayer.load(request)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to play in some fix frame view ?

Comment: Whatever approach, I'll follow if possible. Thanks

Comment: What is your exact issue ? video is not play or it go to full screen?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution as you want, i make player programatically and change some code.

```
var myPlayer: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        webConfiguration.mediaTypesRequiringUserActionForPlayback = []

        myPlayer = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 300), configuration: webConfiguration)
        self.view.addSubview(myPlayer)

        if let videoURL:URL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/embed/9n1e1N0Sa9k?playsinline=1") {
             let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: videoURL)
             myPlayer.load(request)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Bro, you made my day!!!! It works perfectly. Thanks a lot for help, I really appreciate that :)