# Disabling auto-play in full screen on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webkit

The only problem i'm having is that i'm unable to disable playing videos on full screen according to apple documentation this is enabled by default and needs to be set as follows:

```
webView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
```

Which is based on my understanding how it's supposed to be. However this doesn't work and even after configuration right after you press play on video it opens up in native full screen player. I'm using WKWebView.

[Apple's Documentation for this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614793-allowsinlinemediaplayback)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Playing a video *inline* requires two prerequisites:

1. Setting the configuration
2. Providing a correctly formatted link

#### 1. Setting the configuration

The configuration of the WKWebView has needs to be set while initialising. Modifying `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` at a later point will not work:

```
let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height), configuration: configuration)

view.addSubview(webView)
```

#### 2. Providing a correctly formatted link

In order for the web view to know that the video should start playing inline the appropriate URL parameter needs to be set.

For this you simply have to append `?playsinline=1`.

Example:

```
webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OYbXaqQ3uuo?playsinline=1")!))
```

Comment: Well yes thats what i meant to say that its not letting it to play in the video player but goes to native in all cases, so whenever you hit play it automatically switches to full screen native player

Comment: In that case try adding a `?playsinline=1` behind the URL that you are loading.

Comment: Sure let me try

Comment: How do you set the configuration? From what I tried you have to create a `WKWebViewConfiguration` and then initialize the `WKWebView` with this configuration (`WKWebView(frame: CGRect, configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration`). It wont work if you set the configuration afterwards. Here is a sample in a different question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749805/wkwebview-video-inline-ios-xcode

Comment: That actually worked, thanks so much for the help! Submit it as answer so i can accept it!

Comment: apparently webview now has property to enable inline, at least now i know two ways :D

Comment: Setting the "Inline Playback" property on the WKWebView in Interface Builder works just as well. I used this in tandem with the `playsinline` attribute:

`<video playsinline>...</video>`

Answer (score 19):

I faced with this problem using video tag in web view.
I have three videos in the page, and all videos successively played full screen.
I solved this problem by

**1.Check Inline Playback**

[image]

**2.Add playsinline attribute to video tag**

```
<video src="your_videosrc" autoplay playsinline></video>
```

Glad someones help :)

Comment: Other solutions didn't work... except this one! This should be the answer

Comment: I've looked over this for minimum of 10 days, and it was this easy. Thank you for the help, really appreciated it.

Comment: I am new to ios, could someone guide me where to find the setting options to select?

Answer (score 4):

From Storyboad you can check/uncheck Inline playback to stop/allow full screen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue, however it's a slight variation. We have a WkWebView that loads a mobile friendly web application. At various points there are links to videos which work great in that they do open the default iOS video player so the user can go full screen. That's all great. However we have a section where we have some podcasts. I'm trying to use the streaming provider's javascript player for these audio streams but when I press play the native iOS video player takes over. We don't want this because the provider's player has some features we need in it. I've tried adding the ?playsinline=1 but didn't have any affect on the playback. Is it possible to do this without affecting he video playback in the other areas of our app?