# Swift - How to manipulate outlet in nib while "viewWillDisappear" on ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, wkwebview, xib

DetailCollectionViewCell includes a WKWebView that loads specific video and text embedded from the server. My goal is when the user clicks the back button, the video should be stopped. I've tried reloading or setting WebView's URL to nil, but I get Fatal Error and nil value for Web View every time I try to effect detailWebView.

```
.
├── _PageViewController.swift
│   └── viewWillDisappear()
├── _DetailCollectionViewCell.swift (File Owner of the nib)
└── └── WKWebView: detailWebView
```

DetailCollectionViewCell.swift (Where I populate data for WebView.)

```swift
@objc protocol DetailCollectionViewCellDelegate  {
        func reload()
        @objc func scrollAuthorAllColumns()
    }

class DetailCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var detailWeb: WKWebView!
    var delegate: DetailCollectionViewCell?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        detailWeb.navigationDelegate = self
        detailWeb.uiDelegate = self;
        detailWeb.autoresizingMask = UIView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleWidth.rawValue | UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight.rawValue)
    }

    var itemAuthor: Column? {
        didSet {
            if let column = itemAuthor {
                if(PageViewController.itemId != column.itemId) {
                    let webViewHeight = 50 as CGFloat
                    self.webViewHeight.constant = webViewHeight
                    self.wKWebViewHeight.constant = webViewHeight
                    self.detailWeb.frame.size.height = webViewHeight
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                        if(PageViewController.webViewHg <= Int(webViewHeight)) {
                            HUD.show(HUDContentType.progress)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    self.detailWeb.isHidden = true
                    self.delegate?.reload()
                    
                    let HTMLString = "my HTML string"
                    
                    detailWeb.loadHTMLString(String(HTMLString), baseURL: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PageViewController.swift

```swift
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DetailCollectionViewCell.detailWeb.reload() "<--------- Crashes here. detailWebView = nil"
        "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"
    }

    extension PageViewController: DetailCollectionViewCellDelegate {
    func reload() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }
    }
    
    func scrollAuthorAllColumns() {
        collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: 1), at: .top, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: `DetailViewCell` is not a `UITableViewCell` or a `UICollectionView` inside a `UITableView`/`UICollectionView`, I hope. Else, what's `DetailViewCell` inside `PageViewController`? Where is it defined? You could force a load: `DetailViewCell.loadIfNeeded(); DetailsViewCell.detailsWeb.reload()` but I'm wondering if there is not an instance issue too.

Comment: When I use `DetailViewCell.loadIfNeeded()` inside `viewWillDisappear`, I get `Type 'DetailViewCell' has no member 'loadIfNeeded'`. DetailViewCell is a nib custom view, not a UITableViewCell, etc. I also do think this is an instance issue, but I don't know how to work around it. I'd pass data with delegate if this is a View Cell -> View Controller case, but this is a View Controller -> View Cell case.

Comment: What's the supperclass of `DetailViewCell`? How is it initialized? Where is it defined in `PageViewController` I meant `loadViewIfNeeded()` in case it's a UIViewController, but we don't know its type because you didn't gave it.

Comment: `DetailViewCell` is a `UICollectionViewCell` and it didn't defined in `PageViewController`. This is why I put file hierarchy at the beginning of the question. I have 3 files in total; `PageViewController.swift`, `DetailViewCell.swift`, `DetailViewCell.xib`. I register the nib `DetailViewCell` in `viewDidLoad` on `PageViewController` with `collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "DetailViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "DetailViewCell")` and show it in CollectionView defined in `PageViewController.swift`

Comment: Where does DetailViewCell's delegate come from?

Comment: Sorry if I'm being extra dumb because I think this is my 5th hour on this thing. `DetailViewCell` has its own delegate called `DetailViewCellDelegate` and it is used in `PageViewController`. I can pass data to `PageViewController` with the delegate, but can't achieve the same thing in reverse. (Also added delegates to my code)

Comment: What does "I have a two-file project" mean?

Comment: It means something like "only 2 of the files in my project is about this issue".

Comment: `DetailCollectionViewCell.detailWeb.reload()`, you appear to be referencing a static/class property `detailWeb` of `DetailCollectionViewCell` class instead of an instance property, I don't see how this would even compile...`detailWeb` is not a class property

Comment: also, this line `extension PageViewController: DetailCollectionViewCell` should read `extension PageViewController: DetailCollectionViewCellDelegate`

Comment: @1 it compiles, auto-completes the code even. How should I update it? @2 Sorry for the typo it is written in the actual code as you've said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60418480/13116047) method to achieve my goal.

Basically what it does is, disables in-line playback and only allows tvPlayer to play on full-screen thus when the user closes full-screen, the video stops.